# Automatically add paragraphs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

WordPress has a function, `wpautop`, which will automatically wrap paragraph `<p>` tags around any input string.

For example, user inputs:

```
This is a paragraph.

I start another paragraph here. I didn't put in paragraph tags.

You'll have to figure it out, WordPress.
```

After passing through `wpautop`, output string is

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>I start another paragraph here. I didn't put in paragraph tags.</p>

<p>You'll have to figure it out, WordPress.</p>
```

Is there a similar function or plugin available in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `simple_format` method in `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` that translates new lines in texts in HTML paragraphs:

```
simple_format("Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break.")
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"

simple_format("We want to put a paragraph...\n\n...right there.")
# => "<p>We want to put a paragraph...</p>\n\n<p>...right there.</p>"
```

Find more examples in the [Rails Guides](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format).

Comment: Why the downvote? There is nothing wrong with this answer.

Comment: I disagree with the down-vote as well, the answer is correct